# Swift 5: Better way/approach to add image border on photo editing app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

In case the title doesn't make sense, i'm trying to make a photo editing app where user can add border to their photo. For now, i'm testing a white border.

here is a gif sample of the app. (see how slow the slider is. It's meant to be smooth like any other slider.)
[Gif sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeGO8.gif)

My approach was, to render the white background to the image's size, and then render the image n% smaller to shrink it hence the border.

But i have come to a problem where when i'm testing on my device (iphone 7 plus) the slider was so laggy and slow as if it's taking so much time to compute the function.

Here are the codes for the function. This function serves as blend the background with the foreground. Background being plain white colour.

blendImages is a function located on my adjustmentEngine class.

```
func blendImages(backgroundImg: UIImage,foregroundImg: UIImage) -> Data? {
        // size variable
        let contentSizeH = foregroundImg.size.height
        let contentSizeW = foregroundImg.size.width

        // the magic. how the image will scale in the view.
        let topImageH = foregroundImg.size.height - (foregroundImg.size.height * imgSizeMultiplier)
        let topImageW = foregroundImg.size.width - (foregroundImg.size.width * imgSizeMultiplier)

        let bottomImage = backgroundImg
        let topImage = foregroundImg

        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width : contentSizeW, height: contentSizeH))
        let imgView2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: topImageW, height: topImageH))

        // - Set Content mode to what you desire
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imgView2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        // - Set Images
        imgView.image = bottomImage
        imgView2.image = topImage

        imgView2.center = imgView.center

        // - Create UIView
        let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSizeW, height: contentSizeH))
        contentView.addSubview(imgView)
        contentView.addSubview(imgView2)

        // - Set Size
        let size = CGSize(width: contentSizeW, height: contentSizeH)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)
        contentView.drawHierarchy(in: contentView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        guard let i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(),
            let data = i.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
            else {return nil}

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return data
    }
```

Below are the function i called to render it into uiImageView

```
guard let image = image else { return }
let borderColor = UIColor.white.image()

self.adjustmentEngine.borderColor = borderColor
self.adjustmentEngine.image = image

guard let combinedImageData: Data = self.adjustmentEngine.blendImages(backgroundImg: borderColor, foregroundImg: image) else {return}
let combinedImage = UIImage(data: combinedImageData)
self.imageView.image = combinedImage
```

This function will get the image and blend it with a new background colour for the border.

And finally, below are the codes for the slider's didChange function.

```
    @IBAction func sliderDidChange(_ sender: UISlider) {
        print(sender.value)

        let borderColor = adjustmentEngine.borderColor
        let image = adjustmentEngine.image
        adjustmentEngine.imgSizeMultiplier = CGFloat(sender.value)

        guard let combinedImageData: Data = self.adjustmentEngine.blendImages(backgroundImg: borderColor, foregroundImg: image) else {return}
        let combinedImage = UIImage(data: combinedImageData)
        self.imageView.image = combinedImage

    }
```

So the question is, Is there a better way or optimised way to do this? Or a better approach?

Comment: Changing the slider shouldn't actually blend the images. Make your image view sit on top of a white view and the slider should only change the image view's `transform` property to make it smaller. This should be much faster. The actual blending of images should be done when the user presses the "OK" button.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you! i took this into account and modify my code algorithm and it's way faster now!